# I'm not able to get checked property value from datalist's radio button asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, datalist

I am able to get the text and other property of this radio button but it will always return me false for property checked

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="904px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table style="width: 100%;" border="1">            
            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="option1" runat="server" GroupName="Options" Text="A" />

                            <%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "op1") %>
                        </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

C# code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
    {           
        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("option1");
        if (rb1.Checked)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    Response.Write(counter);
}
```

Comment: Did you post the correct markup? I do not see any `RadioButton` control in the markup, nor anything named `option1`.

Comment: Where is radio button?